# Finding the sum and difference of values with the same ID in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a dataframe with only positive values that need to be subtracted with one another, so the initial df looks like:

| date | ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/05/31 | 1 | 100000 |
| 2022/05/31 | 2 | 20000 |
| 2022/05/31 | 3 | 20000 |
| 2022/05/31 | 5 | 50000 |
| 2022/05/31 | 6 | 10000 |
| 2022/05/31 | 7 | 10000 |

I need to take the sum of ID's 2,3 and subtract it from ID 1. Also, i need to take the sum of ID's 6,7 and subtract it from ID 5.

Therefore, the remaining dataframe would have only two values: 60,000 (100,000 - 20,000 - 20,000) and 30000 (50,000 - 10,000 - 10,000).
The desired output would be the following dataframe:

| date | ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/05/31 | 1 | 60000 |
| 2022/05/31 | 2 | 30000 |

So far I have only been able to take the sum of one set of ID's, but then unable to subtract them:

| date | ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/05/31 | 1 | 100000 |
| 2022/05/31 | 2 | 40000 |

So I have been able to subtotal ID 2 & 3, but don't know how to then subtract it from ID 1, then to the same thing with ID's 5 through 7

Would be grateful for any help, thanks

Comment: How do we know that 2,3 need subtracted from 1, and 6,7 need subtracted from 5?  
Is it because if you order them by ID it is always the same pattern?  or do you want the code to literally hard-code the ID numbers (which wouldnt work on new data unless you tweaked the code)

Comment: I would literally hard-code the ID numbers, once they are set I do not expect them to ever change

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, when you post SQL questions its often helpful to include the RDBMS (mySQL, Teradata, Oracle, Snowflake, etc) because SQL syntax is slightly different across all these systems.

I used [Rasgo](https://docs.rasgoml.com/rasgo-docs/transforms/all-transforms) to generate this SQL (which works in Snowflake), but depending on your system you can probably tweak this to work.

You said in the comments that you wanted an answer that works exactly for this set of ID's, so it can be hard-coded. In that case,

```
WITH CTE_CONFIG AS (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE WHEN ID IN('1', '5') THEN 'START' WHEN ID IN('2', '3', '6', '7') THEN 'SUBTRACT' ELSE NULL END AS OPERATION_TO_DO, 
    CASE WHEN ID IN('1', '2', '3') THEN 1 WHEN ID IN('5', '6', '7') THEN 2 ELSE NULL END AS GROUP_ID 
  FROM 
    {{ your_table }}
), 
CTE_AGG AS (
    SELECT 
      GROUP_ID, 
      OPERATION_TO_DO, 
      SUM(MYVALUE) as MYVALUE_SUM 
    FROM 
      CTE_CONFIG 
    GROUP BY 
      GROUP_ID, 
      OPERATION_TO_DO
) 
SELECT 
  GROUP_ID, 
  SUM_START - SUM_SUBTRACT AS ANSWER 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      GROUP_ID, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN OPERATION_TO_DO = 'START' THEN MYVALUE_SUM ELSE 0 END
      ) AS SUM_START, 
      SUM(
        CASE WHEN OPERATION_TO_DO = 'SUBTRACT' THEN MYVALUE_SUM ELSE 0 END
      ) AS SUM_SUBTRACT 
    FROM 
      CTE_AGG 
    GROUP BY 
      GROUP_ID
  ) rs
```

The theory here is that you establish 2 new columns with CASE statements. The first, `OPERATION_TO_DO` will determine whether you are using that ID in the SUBTRACT portion, or the START portion of your equation.

The next column to establish is the `GROUP_ID`, which in your case is ID 1,2,3 and 5,6,7.

Next, we can aggregate the values by `GROUP_ID` and `OPERATION_TO_DO`. Once that's done, we can simply do the math formula that you want.

I thought that you might have a systematic reason for choosing ID 1 and 5, like perhaps it is every 3 records that the cycle starts over. That is certainly possible as well, but since you answered that you wanted to hard-code this, I didn't solve it that way.

If for some reason this syntax doesn't work, I suggest posting a new question with this SQL, tagging the version of SQL you're using, and the error message that you're getting.